# How to I edit a large number of row names in R?

Tags: r

I have 100's of rows I want to edit so I'd rather not do it "manually" via these scripts:

```
a <-data.frame(name=c("A","B","C","D", b=1:4)
rownames(df) <- a$name
```

All rows have the same signifier I want to remove, ".meio", such that the rownames are currently:

A.meio, B.meio, C.meio, D.meio ...

I would like the row names to be
A, B, C, D, etc.

How can I do this efficiently?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **gsub** the function.
Supposedly it works like...

```
> a <- structure(list(name = structure(1:4, .Label = c("A", "B", 
+ "C", 
+ "D"), class = "factor"), b = 1:4), .Names = c("name", "b"), 
+  row.names = c("A.meio", 
+ "B.meio", "C.meio", "D.meio"), class = "data.frame")
> a
        name b
A.meio    A 1
B.meio    B 2
C.meio    C 3
D.meio    D 4
> row.names(a)=gsub(".meio","",row.names(a))
> a
       name b
     A    A 1
     B    B 2
     C    C 3
     D    D 4
```

The difference is that **sub** only replaces the first occurrence of the pattern specified, whereas **gsub** does it for all occurrences (that is, it replaces globally).

Answer (score 2):

We could use `sub` to match the pattern `.` followed by one or more characters (`.*`) to the end of the string (`$`) and replace it with `''`.

```
row.names(a) <- sub("\\..*$", '', row.names(a))
```

NOTE: From the example showed by the OP, it seems that there is only a single instance of `.meio`, so `sub` is sufficient.

#### data

```
a <- structure(list(name = structure(1:4, .Label = c("A", "B", 
"C", 
"D"), class = "factor"), b = 1:4), .Names = c("name", "b"), 
 row.names = c("A.meio", 
"B.meio", "C.meio", "D.meio"), class = "data.frame")
```